# Work around SpellCheckerSession leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I discovered my `Activity` is leaking on the ICS emulator. HProf seemed to show `SpellCheckerSession` keeping a reference to my `Activity` around, and there appears to have been a fix:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/df3722895172e03c81787f62d922daabaad3e20b

But is there any way to work around this in the mean time? Can I disable spell checking somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Does it need a `Context`? Maybe pass the `Application` `Context` by using `activity.getApplicationContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the same issue. The workaround was to disable spell checking for all EditText fields.

See my response here: [Why does EditView retain its Activity's Context in Ice Cream Sandwich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497965/why-does-editview-retain-its-activitys-context-in-ice-cream-sandwich/15190491#15190491)