# Android Samsung Memory leak in EditText

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks

I encountered a memory leak with Samsung devices. 
If some activity has `EditText` this activity will be leaked. 
To show this I created a small test applications.

First `Activity` (called `MyActivity`) contains `EditText` and `Button`. By pressing a button you call finish() on first `Activity` and open second one.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    findViewById(R.id.goTo)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

When I am on second Activity I take a hprof. From Memory Analyzer I see that MyActivity is leaked because of reference from InputMethodManager

[image: Screenshot from Memory Analyzer]

This problem occurs only in Samsung S III and Tab devices. So there is no leak in Xperia P device and others. Please help how to bypass this error.

Comment: I am not sure about this but what i done is just place finifh() after startActivity(); Try this.

Comment: Thank you but this didn't fix the problem. Still there is a link from InputMethodManager to my activity

Comment: I am using the same device and tried the code and not having memory leak issue. May be at some other point the issue. I am not sure about that.

Comment: I just uploaded full project into https://github.com/rdautov/EditTextMemoryLeakTest. Please try this code.

Comment: There is a SoftReference in the reference link. Do you still consider it a memory leak?

Comment: Anyone found any solution?

Comment: Maybe this workaround might help you : stackoverflow.com/a/27231817/1532108

Comment: @gbero Clickable link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27231817/356895