# EditText and DialogFragment causing OutOfMemory crash

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-edittext, android-dialogfragment

I am encountering an annoying memory leak and crash that seems to be a platform bug. I'm trying to debug /another/ memory issue, but I keep finding this EditText related bug keeping hold of my views and that which is in those.

Given a DialogFragment, a layout with an EditText and UI Monkey I can make the following simple app crash due to an Out Of Memory exception.

I've tested on x86 emulators 17 - 19 with the latest updates as of March 21 2014 with a heap of 16MB. On a Nexus 4 on 4.4.2 I see the memory leak increasing and increasing and increasing over a five minute period but have never left it long enough to see it crash, but the same leakage is shown when looking at the N4's memory dump.

The Activity opens a DialogFragment when an option menu is pressed:

```
package org.example.edittextoom;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        DialogFragment df = new Df();
        df.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialogtag");
        return true;
    }

    public static class Df extends DialogFragment {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Dialog onCreateDialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
            return onCreateDialog;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Using inflator from app context instead to attempt to avoid the issue with EditTexts holding onto Activity's
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.dialog, container, false);
                    // Since disabling no suggestions is suppose to prevent the edit text leak
                    EditText et = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    int it = et.getInputType();
                    et.setInputType(it | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
                    it = et.getInputType();
            return view;
        }

    }

}
```

The two layouts are simple. The dialogue has an EditText.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

</RelativeLayout>
```

dialog.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Let's see the memory leak by running UI Monkey.

```
adb shell monkey -p org.example.edittextoom --pct-nav 0 --pct-majornav 0 --pct-appswitch 0 800000
```

(If you're going to run this, run it on an x86 emulator with the lowest screen size for increased speed.)

While it's running you can also confirm it's taking up increasing amount of memory by looking at the the fifth column here, over about a minute or so (incidentally, it generally crashes at about 56000):

```
$ adb shell ps | grep edittext
u0_a46    2727  794   177888 31596 ffffffff b7f34997 S com.example.edittextoom
$ adb shell ps | grep edittext
u0_a46    2727  794   177888 31784 ffffffff b7f3322a S com.example.edittextoom
$ adb shell ps | grep edittext
u0_a46    2727  794   177956 31852 ffffffff b7f34997 S com.example.edittextoom
$ adb shell ps | grep edittext
u0_a46    2727  794   178124 32064 ffffffff b7f3322a S com.example.edittextoom
```

Then it will eventually crash (around event 150,000 to 500,000 I found) outputting:

```
// CRASH: com.example.edittextoom (pid 13620)
// Short Msg: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
// Long Msg: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
// Build Label: generic_x86/sdk_x86/generic_x86:4.2/JOP40C/eng.android-build.20121231.103448:eng/test-keys
// Build Changelist: eng.android-build.20121231.103448
// Build Time: 1356921334000
// java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
//      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
//      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
//      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
//      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
//      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
//      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660)
//      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2832)
//      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2875)
//      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:285)
//      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:279)
//      at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:482)
//      at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onActivityCreated(DialogFragment.java:366)
//      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1508)
//      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
//      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
//      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
//      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
//      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
//      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
//      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
//      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
//      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
//      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
//      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
//      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
//      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
//      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
//
** Monkey aborted due to error.
Events injected: 131816
:Sending rotation degree=0, persist=false
:Dropped: keys=1534 pointers=13377 trackballs=0 flips=0 rotations=0
## Network stats: elapsed time=308525ms (0ms mobile, 0ms wifi, 308525ms not connected)
** System appears to have crashed at event 131816 of 800000 using seed 1393322223373
```

(Sometimes the emulator keeps taking up memory, and kills the app, but you don't get a force close dialogue, so UI Monkey goes into a loop, playing with the emulator until it brings up the app again, but the app is killed by the system after taking up so much memory regardless.)

If you stop UI monkey mid flow, by cancelling its process, you can inspect the hprof in MAT to see what's taking up the memory (I exit the app and do a force gc before looking at the hprof), to see that it's retaining only one MainPageActivity but 63 instancess MainPageActivity$Df, and that's after running for only a minute or so. I get the same thing looking at the memory dump on my Nexus 4.

If you list the incoming references to one of those, and click Path To GC Roots and exclude weak and soft references, you get this (It's the same of all the other 63 references from what I can see):

[image]

If, however, I change the EditText in the dialogue to a ProgressBar with an id or a TextView with an id, I do not get this crash or the memory leakage shown in MAT. So I believe it's related to this [EditText causing memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069501/edittext-causing-memory-leak) bug, however, none of the work-arounds work, not nulling the EditText's InputConnection nor turning off suggestions (which I've done in the example above). I also manage to rid myself of the leak if I remove the id of the EditText, but then I can't access my EditTexts.

Have you seen similar, found a work around or if you can see something remiss in my code?

This issue is currently preventing me from properly looking for memory leaks in my application.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue. Having an EditText inside a Dialog leaks memory because of Blink inside Editor. This happens to Samsung Tab 10 4.4.2, but doesn't happen to Nexus 7 4.4.2, which is strange.

The only way to get around it is to disable cursor in the EditText. Use setCursorVisible(false). If you want your cursor to blink, you can disable cursor right before dismissing the dialog, this prevents the Blinker to schedule itself again.

Note: rana's suggestion is plainly wrong. He doesn't understand the difference between a static nested class and a non-static inner class at all. Non-static inner class will hold an implicit reference to your activity, so in fact you DO want to use static nested class here, which is the SAME as declaring this class in a separate file.

Comment: I haven't tested this but this seems like the likeliest answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Custom View substitute DialogFragment, or use Dialog

Answer (score -1):

Declare DialogFragment df as part of the activity. you will be fine.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? The DialogFragment is a static inner class in the activity and it's initialized in the Activity.

Comment: Either move Dialogfragment in a seperate file or remove the static tag. It shouldnt be static at all.

Comment: hows does my answer get newgetive response . its engineering 101 when you declare a dialogfragment as static and being used by one of the non-static class it will leak as the non-static class will try to get garbaged  and it is holding this static member and hence the leak