# Memory leak on EditText with ImageSpan

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I'm developing a text editor with EditText and ImageSpan. I could managed it but I'm getting  memory leaks sometimes: When I insert a new image.

I got a Memory dump with DDMS and open it with MAT. I've seen the images as byte[], but the list of objects with incoming references is empty; so I can't know where the memory leaks are being produced.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [EditText causing memory leak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069501/edittext-causing-memory-leak)

Comment: you mean you have leaks not when you insert a new ImageSpan but when you delete it?

Comment: I've read the other question and I don't think it's the same question because in the MAT screen captures I can see where the memory is retained while in my case I can't get the references to the byte[] that holds the bitmap.

Comment: I load text from the disk to the EditText and insert an ImageSpan to represent the image. When I finish the activity (back button) some times the memory held by the bitmap shown in the EditText is not free though I can't see in MAT which objects held a reference to this bitmap. As the images are big (just full screen) in some executions of the activity I got an OutOfMemoryError